# layer transparency does not work java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to write a paint app that has a use of layers. I currently have 4 layers, the bottom one is white color and all other are transparent. Meanwhile I have only the 3rd(top) layer drawing to the buffered image, others for some reason only show preview but do not commit to the image. Also even though I implemented the transparency of the layers, it does not take affect. All the layers are black. The good part is that is shows the top most layer at all times. Please help

```
    public class Canvas extends JComponent implements MouseWheelListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private final List<BufferedImage> images;
private DrawListenerInterface listenerInterface;
private int activeLayer;
private final Color color;

private final Paint frame;

public Canvas(Paint frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
    this.images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
    this.activeLayer = 0;
    this.color = Color.red;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        images.add(new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));

        setLayers(i);
    }

    this.addMouseWheelListener(this);

}
```

---

```
    public class Canvas extends JComponent implements MouseWheelListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private final List<BufferedImage> images;
private DrawListenerInterface listenerInterface;
private int activeLayer;
private final Color color;

private final Paint frame;

public Canvas(Paint frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
    this.images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
    this.activeLayer = 0;
    this.color = Color.red;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        images.add(new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));

        setLayers(i);
    }

    this.addMouseWheelListener(this);

}

public void setListeners(DrawListenerInterface listener) {

    if (listenerInterface != null) {
        this.removeMouseListener(listenerInterface);
        this.removeMouseMotionListener(listenerInterface);

    }
    this.listenerInterface = listener;
    this.addMouseMotionListener(listenerInterface);
    this.addMouseListener(listenerInterface);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // defaultSettings((Graphics2D) g);

    final Iterator<BufferedImage> iter = images.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        // g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER));
        g.drawImage(iter.next(), 0, 0, null);
        this.repaint();

    }
    listenerInterface.preview((Graphics2D) g);
    this.repaint();
    // g2.drawImage(images.get(activeLayer), 0, 0, null);

    // }
    // g2.setColor(color);

}

public BufferedImage getImage() {
    return images.get(activeLayer);
}

public int getActiveLayer() {
    return activeLayer;
}

public void setActiveLayer(int activeLayer) {
    this.activeLayer = activeLayer;
}

public void setLayers(int layerNumber) {
    // System.out.println(layer);
    if (layerNumber == 0) {
        final Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) images.get(0).getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    } else {
        BufferedImage img = images.get(layerNumber);
        img = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        final Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
        graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR));
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
        // reset composite
        graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER));

    }

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

---

```
    public class DrawListener implements DrawListenerInterface {

private final Canvas canvas;
private int x, y;
private int x2;
private int y2;
private final Paint frame;

public DrawListener(Canvas canvas, Paint frame) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.frame = frame;
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.x2 = e.getX();
    this.y2 = e.getY();
    final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) canvas.getImage().getGraphics();
    draw(g2);
    canvas.repaint();
    x = x2;
    y = y2;
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    g2.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    x = e.getX();
    x2 = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    y2 = e.getY();
    final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) canvas.getImage().getGraphics();
    draw(g2);
    canvas.repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void preview(Graphics2D g2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

---

```
 public class LayerPanel extends JPanel {

private final JButton layer0, layer1, layer2, layer3;
private final Canvas canvas;

public LayerPanel(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    this.canvas = canvas;

    this.setSize(new Dimension(200, 400));
    this.layer0 = new JButton("Layer 0");
    this.layer1 = new JButton("Layer 1");
    this.layer2 = new JButton("Layer 2");
    this.layer3 = new JButton("Layer 3");

    this.layer0.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    this.layer1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    this.layer2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    this.layer3.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));

    this.add(layer3);
    this.add(layer2);
    this.add(layer1);
    this.add(layer0);

}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        layer0.setBackground(Color.gray);
        layer1.setBackground(Color.gray);
        layer2.setBackground(Color.gray);
        layer3.setBackground(Color.gray);
        if (e.getSource().equals(layer0)) {
            canvas.setActiveLayer(0);
            final JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
            b.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        } else if (e.getSource().equals(layer1)) {
            canvas.setActiveLayer(1);
            final JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
            b.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        } else if (e.getSource().equals(layer2)) {
            canvas.setActiveLayer(2);
            final JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
            b.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        } else if (e.getSource().equals(layer3)) {
            canvas.setActiveLayer(3);
            final JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
            b.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }

    }

}
```

---

```
public interface DrawListenerInterface extends MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

public void draw(Graphics2D g2);

public void preview(Graphics2D g2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `super.paintComponent(g)` in `Canvas` indirectly calls `ComponentUI.update(..)`:

```
public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    if (c.isOpaque()) {
        g.setColor(c.getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight());
    }
    paint(g, c);
}
```

So unless you call `setOpaque(false)` on the component at some point, you are always filling `g` with the background color.

I'd try setting opaque to `false` or remove the `super.paintComponent(g)` call.

There seem to be other issues with the code as well.
The images you create in the `Canvas` constructor are all `TYPE_INT_RGB`, i.e. they *do not support* an alpha channel/transparency.
But then later in `setLayers()` for layers other than 0, you retrieve the image `img` and then overwrite it with a new, transparency-supporting image, that you *never stored anywhere*:

```
BufferedImage img = images.get(layerNumber);
img = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

`img` is lost right after you leave the corresponding block.

Comment: your answer did not help me directly, however my entire problem was in having bufferedImage of type TYPE_INT_RGB, one changed for TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE all started working. So you deserve a big +1

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you are actually asking, but:

```
BufferedImage img = images.get(layerNumber);
img = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
final Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR));
graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
// reset composite
graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER));
```

You are not storing the `img` anywhere, even though you create a new instance for it. Also there's no point in getting it from the `images` and then right after setting it to something else.